# How do I stop searchkit from displaying a deleted event registration

Tags: searchkit

Here is the scenario...

Person registers twice for an event using different emails. We merge the contact, they show up as being registered twice for the event. No big deal, we delete the extra registration. Everything looks good in the system.

Except, when I run a search in searchkit, the person shows up twice.

Is my search incorrectly setup, or is the system pulling the deleted information somehow. This happens to happen when I also want website information to also appear. If I remove the website info, it appears correctly.

Below is my search query.

```
{
  "version": 4,
  "select": [
    "display_name",
    "first_name",
    "last_name",
    "employer_id.display_name",
    "Contact_Website_contact_id_01.url",
    "Custom_Fields.Sector:label",
    "Custom_Fields.Industry:label",
    "Contact_Participant_contact_id_01.register_date",
    "Contact_Participant_contact_id_01.role_id:label",
    "Contact_Participant_contact_id_01.status_id:label"
  ],
  "orderBy": [],
  "where": [
    [
      "contact_type:name",
      "=",
      "Individual"
    ]
  ],
  "groupBy": [],
  "join": [
    [
      "Participant AS Contact_Participant_contact_id_01",
      "INNER",
      [
        "id",
        "=",
        "Contact_Participant_contact_id_01.contact_id"
      ],
      [
        "Contact_Participant_contact_id_01.event_id",
        "=",
        "\"12\""
      ],
      [
        "Contact_Participant_contact_id_01.status_id:name",
        "=",
        "\"Registered\""
      ]
    ],
    [
      "Website AS Contact_Website_contact_id_01",
      "LEFT",
      [
        "id",
        "=",
        "Contact_Website_contact_id_01.contact_id"
      ],
      [
        "Contact_Website_contact_id_01.url",
        "IS NOT EMPTY"
      ]
    ]
  ],
  "having": []
}
```

Comment: Does the contact have 2 websites?

Comment: Hi @Aidan thank you - I thats the answer!